# Automatically generate C++ Source and Header (and update vice versa on changes) files

Tags: c++, emacs, header, automation

Is there some tool (hopefully emacs) that can update and add the correct function definitions and other things to keep the source (.cpp) and the header (.h) files synchronized.

For example if I start doing this:

```
file: aaa.h

Class AAA {
   int b;
public:
   void func();
};
```

something that will automatically create and add:

```
file: aaa.cpp

void AAA:func() {

}
```

And any changes will appear on both?

Am I just dreaming too much?

Answer (score 7):

An almost duplicate question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652779/automatically-separate-class-definitions-from-declarations) and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652779/automatically-separate-class-definitions-from-declarations/653758#653758) describes the tool that we use to go from a single file to separate header and source files: [lzz](http://www.lazycplusplus.com).

I don't know of any tool that can do the reverse translation.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio + [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com) does it (see Refactoring features).

But indeed, it's not emacs based :/

Comment: Just to clarify, VA does not do this completely automatically.  You would need to invoke Create Implementation to create a stub implementation from the declaration.  You would need to run Change Signature to modify both the declaration and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Xrefactory (fairly expensive tool) might be able to do what you are looking for.  I haven't used it (I use Visual Studio + Visual Assist myself) but it shows up on a google search for 'emacs refactoring tools'.