# Visual studio: automatically update C++ cpp/header file when the other is changed?

Tags: visual-c++, refactoring, vsx, header-files, automated-refactoring

For example, if I change the signature in a function in either the header or the cpp, I'd like it to automatically change in the other one. If I add a new function in either, it should appear in both. If I delete a function, it could probably comment out the other one.
Manually having to duplicate one's changes seems silly.

Some people have mentioned http://www.lazycplusplus.com/ in response to a similar question, but it seems that that's a command line tool which would require saving and then running this external tool on a particular file. That's still more manual steps than I would have thought were necessary; I'd like this to apply changes **as I type**.

Comment: I was looking for that feature too, but didn't find it up to now...
But http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976467/automatically-generate-c-source-and-header-and-update-vice-versa-on-changes-f tells that there is some solution.

Comment: Microsoft have recently released a free extension that performs rename (only) refactoring within Visual C++. See [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/164904b2-3b47-417f-9b6b-fdd35757d194)

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is refactoring in Visual C++ which is unfortunately only available via third-party plugins and to my knowledge not in an "as you type" fashion.

I'm using the excellent [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) which allows for renaming methods, changing signatures and much more.

Comment: I agree that VA X is good, but I find having to manually drill down to "change signature" and editing it inside a dialog almost the same effort as copy/pasting. Would be great if it all just worked automatically.

Comment: Yes, indeed. But at least it also updates the references to the renamed methods which is a huge helper when there are many calls of the particular method.

However, C++ is a rather complex language and current refactoring solutions are almost not comparable to what exists for Java or C#.