# Lazy C++ - Chicken and Egg Problem

Tags: c++, build, circular-dependency

Based on feedback I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369958/moving-c-method-declarations-from-hh-to-cc-file), I'm interested in using Lazy C++ on my OSX laptop. The [Lazy C++ webpage](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/) has binaries for Linux and Windows available, but nothing for OSX. There's also a link to download for the Lazy C++ source, but it requires a lzz binary as part of the build process. This creates a situation where I need an lzz binary in order to get an lzz binary.

How can I build lzz on my laptop without an lzz binary? Do I need to do part of the build on a Linux or Windows machine to preprocess the lzz source files, and then transfer the source over to my laptop for building? Or is there something else that I should try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that Lazy C++ appears to be a sort of a preprocessor - generating source files as output - you could probably compile it to completion on a supported platform like Windows, take all the generated files and compile it from these generated files again on OSX.

Depending on how complex the build system (Makefiles, in this case) of Lazy C++ is - this is going to be trivial, very complicated or anywhere in between...

Comment: This is exactly what happened, except that the author of lzz was kind enough to mail me the results of the step that required lzz to generate. Looks like it was trivial, thanks for the suggestion!