# A tool to auto separate C++ header and implementation

Tags: c++

I always feel a pain when I switch from C# or python back to C++ and meet the .h and .cpp separation.

So I thought that maybe there is a tool that at pre-compilation step can take header (o file with some special extension) and split it to .h and .cpp?

So if original file like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:

    void HaHaHa()
    {
       //some logic
    }
 }
```

And a result would be as .h and .cpp files:

```
//.h 

class MyClass
{
public:

    void HaHaHa();
}

// .cpp 

#include "MyClass.h"

void MyClass::HaHaHa() 
{
    //some logic
}
```

Some googling didn't show up the ready to use tools. But I'm pretty sure it is not a new idea and such tools should exist.

P.S. It is known that i.e.  Visual Assist X and VIM has tools to handle .h and .cpp separation with less pain. But I'm asking about a possibility to have a code in one files and separate them automatically as a part of build process.

Comment: And why not then put all code in the h files?  Slow compiles?

Comment: Modules will sooner (or later) come to c++, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596147/modules-in-c0x this will solve it hopefully.

Comment: "Slow compiles" - as example. Slow parsers of autocomplition is even worse. Or sometimes one write some library and don't want it to be "open source". In general, C++ is designed to have this separation. In this point of view having such tool is much clear solution.

Comment: @tauran I wish it to come sooner! But unfortunately today we live in "today" and not in "tomorrow"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically split (refactor) .h into header and implementation (h+cpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184366/automatically-split-refactor-h-into-header-and-implementation-hcpp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically generate C++ file from header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404614/automatically-generate-c-file-from-header)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This tool may help you: [lazycplusplus](https://web.archive.org/web/20191031213115/http://www.lazycplusplus.com/)  *[Wayback link because the domain was lost]*

Project repo: https://github.com/mjspncr/lzz3

Comment: Thank you! That looks really what I was asking! Now it is time to check it in action...

Comment: Given that the parser has been hand-made, I am skeptical about its ability to parse real C++ statements: templates, function types, ...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going about it backwards: you want to write the header
file, without the implementations, before writing the code.  What would
be nice is a tool which would read the header file and generate the
outline code for the implementation: with namespaces, nested classes and
such, just the wrappers can be quite verbose.  But the closest I've seen
is Rational Rose, which starts with a (highly) annotated ULM diagram,
and generates both the header and the boilerplate of the implementation.
It's a very nice tool—I use it whenever it's available—but
it's a bit pricy for the home user, and probably even for small
corporations.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/) by Whole Tomato does [that sort of thing](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/featureRefactoring.asp). Not automated though I don't think.

Comment: @Majestic - It is not the least obvious what you mean by VAX  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VAX